# Xna/Monogame How to get an object to decelerate

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

So I've written a statement for releasing the ball based on a certain speed and for it to move in the direction of the mouse, like so:

```
            MouseX = stateOfTheMouse.X;
            MouseY = stateOfTheMouse.Y;
            difference = Vector2.Subtract(position, new Vector2(MouseX, MouseY));
            direction = Vector2.Normalize(difference);
            velocity.X -= ((float)(usedSpeed / 2));
            velocity.Y -= ((float)(usedSpeed / 2));
```

Then in my updateI call this

```
            position += velocity * direction;
```

I assign usedSpeed as an integer with the press of a NumPad key 1-5 each on reflects the speed amount hence NumPad1 = speed of 1, etc.

Therefore, how would I make the velocity decelerate and slow down to a complete stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decelerate your object by multiplying its velocity with value smaller than 1 and greater than 0, the smaller the value, the faster it decelerates. For example:

```
public readonly float Friction = 0.98f;
/* ... */

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    /* your code here */

    velocity *= Friction; // Here we go
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update method, just reduce the velocity (increase if negative, otherwise decrease)

```
var resistence = -0.05f; // change this
if (velocity.X != 0)
{
    if (velocity.X < 0) { velocity.X += resistance; }

    if (velocity.X > 0 ) 
    {
        velocity.X -= resistance;
    }
}

if (this.vel.Y != 0)
{
    if (this.vel.Y < 0) { this.vel.Y += resistance; }

    if (this.vel.Y > 0 && tempY == this.vel.Y) 
    { 
        this.vel.Y -= resistance; 
    }
}
```